# CRON to Clear out /tmp files older than 30min old

Tags: cron

the servers root /tmp directory has been getting full with file uploads. These files should be removed once the upload is done, but in some cases it hasn't. As i investigate that issue. Im looking for a cron task to delete files that start 202 from the /tmp directory that's 30 minutes old that runs every 30 minutes.

So far, i have `/30  * * * rm -rf /tmp/202*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution. Works pretty well.

```
0 * * * *  find /tmp -regextype posix-egrep -regex '/tmp/[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6}-.*-file-.*' -type f -mmin +60 -delete
```